# Xamarin Forms RefreshView stopped working randomly

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The RefreshView was just working yesterday and today I can't get it to work in any page. I created a brand new page with just a RefreshView and when I try to pull down it doesn't budge. Doesn't pull down, doesn't refresh, nothing. It was just working last night and today after no code changes it's not working. I've tried on the simulator and on my actual iPad. Before anyone suggests, there are no updates to any of my NuGet packages and I can't find any reference to this issue on Google.

XF: v5.0.0.2244

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage
    x:Class="MyApp.UI.Pages.PricingPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.Core.ViewModels;assembly=MyApp.Core"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    x:DataType="viewModels:PricingViewModel"
    x:TypeArguments="viewModels:PricingViewModel">
    <views:MvxContentPage.Content>
        <RefreshView Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" />
        </RefreshView>
    </views:MvxContentPage.Content>
</views:MvxContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyApp.Core.ChurromigosApi;
using MyApp.Core.Services;
using MyApp.Core.ViewModels.Base;
using MvvmCross.Commands;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace MyApp.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class PricingViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly IMenuItemService menuItemService;

        public PricingViewModel(IMenuItemService menuItemService)
        {
            this.menuItemService = menuItemService;

            this.RefreshCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(this.Refresh);
            this.MenuItems = new MvxObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
            this.Title = "Pricing";
        }

        public MvxObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public IMvxAsyncCommand RefreshCommand { get; }

        public bool IsRefreshing { get; set; }

        public override Task Initialize()
        {
            this.IsRefreshing = true;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task Refresh()
        {
            var allMenuItems = await this.menuItemService.GetMenuItems(CancellationToken.None);

            this.MenuItems.Clear();
            this.MenuItems.AddRange(allMenuItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mysterious problems are the worst. Things I would try, checking after each to see if it works: 1) reboot. 2) Rebuild Solution. 3) thoroughly clean by deleting all bin and obj folders (first saving to repo or copying entire solution to another folder, in case accidentally delete something important). 4) Create an entirely new solution, create a new page, see if that works.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: @Jason updated with code instead of image

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve tried all that already :(

Comment: Could you please post relative error log about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem with `RefreshView`, though in my case instead of becoming unresponsive, the app just crashes.

It appears that we need to pay more attention to the binding `Mode` for the property used for the `IsRefreshing` indicator:

- If we want the `RefreshView` to automatically trigger the command when the VM's binded property is changed to True, then don't include a `Mode`, or use `Mode=TwoWay`, but don't manually change the value or you'll be stuck in a loop (or include a `if(IsRefreshing) return;` in your command or you wont get any results)
- If we want to manually set the VM's property in the backend to show/hide the `IsRefreshing` activity indicator without triggering the command, then use `Mode=OneWay` or else you will be stuck in a loop.

In your particular case it could be related to the fact that you're setting your `IsRefreshing` property to `true`, and then you never set it back to `false`? I would wrap your `Refreshing()` method's code with a `try`, setting `IsRefreshing=false` at the beginning and then `=false` in a `finally` block.